# PRISM-MVVM, ItemsControl problem with View injection

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, checkbox, command, itemscontrol

I need to display multiple instances of a basketDetailsView.xaml within a region placed in basketView.xaml, but I'm getting the following errormessage when i debug my code:

"An exception occurred while creating a region with name 'basketRegion'. The exception was: System.InvalidOperationException: ItemsControl's ItemsSource property is not empty. This control is being associated with a region, but the control is already bound to something else. If you did not explicitly set the control's ItemSource property, this exception may be caused by a change in the value of the inherited RegionManager attached property"

The basketView XAML contains an ItemsControl tag defined like this

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="basketItemsControl"cal:RegionManager.RegionName="basketRegion"/>
```

The view also has a listbox where I can uncheck/check the BasketDetailsViews I want to look at:

```
<ListBox x:Name="basketListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding basket}"  MinWidth="200">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
  <CheckBox commands:Checked1.Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckCommand,ElementName=basketListBox}" Content="{Binding basketName}" ></CheckBox>
</DataTemplate>       
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox
```

When I run without debugging it executes fine and I can pop in/out the different basketDetailsViews, but when debugging the above mentioned error shows. What Am i doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
Public Sub AddCageDetailsView(ByVal BasketName As String)
Dim basketRegion = _RegionManager.Regions("basketRegion")
Dim view = _Container.Resolve(Of basketDetailsView)()
Dim viewmodel = _Container.Resolve(Of basketDetailsViewModel)()

view.ApplyModel(viewmodel)
basketRegion.Add(view)
End Sub
```

So basketRegion is the region in my ItemsControl as specified above. This region is supposed to hold my basketDetailsViews..

Comment: Wow, I'm really stuck on this one, it seems like I'm running into an issue that is a bug in the CAL!
See this thread: http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=213889
How can I get around this?

Comment: Where did you register your view with the region?

Comment: Checkbox fires a command, when that command is handled in the viewmodel for BasketView.xaml I run a method called: AddBasketDetailsView. See my EDIT in intial post for details of method.